# PVC for EFS volume fails with "ValidationError: Request ARN is invalid"

Tags: amazon-eks, amazon-efs, kubernetes-pvc, validationerror

I am trying to use EFS as the persistent storage for some EKS pods. I have installed the AWS EFS CSI Driver, created a File System in EFS and a storage class in EKS. When I try to mount a volume to a pod, the PVC fails with the error -

```
  Type     Reason              Age   From                                                                           Message
  ----     ------              ----  ----                                                                           -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  19s   efs.csi.aws.com_ip-xxxx.xxx.com_7598289c-9f51-4b83-9a4e-02ff9942af9a  failed to provision volume with StorageClass "efs-sc": rpc error: code = Internal desc = Failed to fetch File System info: Describe File System failed: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: ValidationError: Request ARN is invalid
           status code: 400, request id: 2af47ad1-c5ce-4389-a716-8f0e241145a7
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong. I have set up the CSI driver by following the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/efs-csi.html) and have the proper IRSA set up as per the document. I expected that the PVC would be bound and the pod would go in running state but the PVC stays unbound and the pod goes into pending state.
This is my first time using EFS and I am kind of clueless right now. Any guidance is really appreciated. Is there any way to dig deeper and understand why it throws the error it does as I have ensured that the fileSystemId in the storage class is the same as the file system ID shown in the EFS console? What might I be missing?

The AWS EFS CSI driver controller logs show the following fileSystemId which is the same as the one in AWS console.

```
I0729 06:59:09.646688       1 controller.go:61] CreateVolume: called with args {Name:pvc-649527dd-78bf-4aaa-9688-2496bb181d6c CapacityRange:required_bytes:68719476736  VolumeCapabilities:[mount:<mount_flags:"tls" > access_mode:<mode:MULTI_NODE_MULTI_WRITER > ] Parameters:map[basePath:/dynamic_provisioning csi.storage.k8s.io/pv/name:pvc-649527dd-78bf-4aaa-9688-2496bb181d6c csi.storage.k8s.io/pvc/name:prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-db-prometheus-prometheus-kube-prometheus-prometheus-2 csi.storage.k8s.io/pvc/namespace:monitoring directoryPerms:755 fileSystemId:fs-08121f8be9526a369 gidRangeEnd:70000 gidRangeStart:1000 provisioningMode:efs-ap] Secrets:map[] VolumeContentSource:<nil> AccessibilityRequirements:<nil> XXX_NoUnkeyedLiteral:{} XXX_unrecognized:[] XXX_sizecache:0}
I0729 06:59:09.646782       1 cloud.go:238] Calling DescribeFileSystems with input: {
  FileSystemId: "fs-08121f8be9526a369"
}

[EFS console screenshot][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6HNd.png
```

Comment: It looks like the error is related to service account. Is the service account annotated with correct IAM role ARN for EFS CSI Driver?

Comment: Yes. The service account on the controller has the correct IAM role ARN in its annotation.

Comment: Error is saying invalid ARN, did you follow the instructions at this link (https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/efs-create-filesystem.md) to create your efs volumes?
Also check your security groups to for inbound and outbound rules, and that you are using amazon dns server for your vpc.

Comment: @greemwahr  Yes I understood what the error is saying which kinda stumped me as I ensured to set up the security group mentioned at the link you provided and also, I have attached the SG to the EFS file system. I did not need to create a volume manually as I am looking at dynamic provisioning. But the security groups and steps mentioned in the documentations, I have followed.

Comment: Can you share your kubectl logs?

Comment: @greemwahr Sure, I'd love to. Which logs do you want? The CSI controller pod logs or a describe of the PVC or both?

Comment: Both will be more helpful if you don’t mind?

Comment: If you are still having issues with the installation you can try the just released managed-addon which makes integration easier https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/08/amazon-eks-configure-efs-shared-file-storage/

Answer (score 0):

usually you get ARN invlaid error is when you give incorrect arn names, In the referred document ARN is mainly used in 3 places -
One in the seciton - "Principal": "Federated"  in the policy
and in service acccount metadata annotations,  make sure you add the correct arn from your account. In policy search for efs-eks-AmazonEFSCSIDriverPolicyRole and make sure you add the correct arn and replace the accountId

something like

annotations:
eks.amazonaws.com/role-arn: arn:aws:iam::YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID:role/COMP/apps/services/entarch/efs-eks-AmazonEFSCSIDriverPolicyRole-REMAINING_VALUES_REPLACE